# Cannot import name 'pb'

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted

I'm using Twisted 16.1.1 and python 3.4. On twisted's documentation for version 16.1.1, [there is a tutorial](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/pb.html) that says `from twisted.spread import pb'. But when I try to import it it gives an exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
from twisted.spread import pb
ImportError: cannot import name 'pb'
```

I'm follwing [this tutorial](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-usage.html). This is my code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.spread import pb

class Echoer(pb.Root):
    def remote_echo(self, st):
        print('echoing:', st)
        return st

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.listenTCP(8789, pb.PBServerFactory(Echoer()))
    reactor.run()
```

On `/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/twisted/spread` there is on one folder named  `ui`. There is not a folder/file called pb.

I copied the `pb.py` file to my python folder, now when I try to import pb I get an Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
from twisted.spread import pb
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/Twisted-16.1.1-py3.4.egg/twisted/spread/pb.py", line 890
except Error, e:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is happening?

Comment: Did you run the `setup.py` file to add twisted to python properly?

Comment: I installed it from pip...

Comment: I can import `from twisted.internet import reactor`, but pb no.

Comment: could you please post the code? There isn't any obvious reason this should be failing. Also, do you create a file called `pb.py` anywhere in that directory?

Comment: I edited my question with my code.

Comment: Hmm you may be encountering [One of These Problems](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html). This site should hopefully give you all the information you need to know to fix your problem.

Comment: I edited my question, but I have no idea where to go now.

Comment: Given that there is no `pb.py` file under `twister/spread` i'd say that your installation is either incomplete, or the x86-64 version does not have it. Try installing the 32bit version. The [Tarball from Here](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads) has the `pb.py` file under `spread`.

Comment: I installed this tarball using setup.py install, but it not copy pb.py to spread folder. I think I'll try to copy and paste...

Comment: If you look at the twisted python 3 porting graph (https://rawgit.com/mythmon/twisted-py3-graph/master/index.html), you'll see that twisted.spread.pb hasn't been ported yet. It's currently available with python 2 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the *SyntaxError* is that `except Error, e:` in only valid in Python 2.   In Python 3, it would be written `except Error as e:`.

The problem isn't with your code.  The underlying module hasn't yet been updated to Python 3.